# Got "Cannot GET /" after add middleware function

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am learning Node.js and Express now. I have a problem that is when I add my middleware function into my code as below:

```
var express = require('express');
var http = require('http');
var app = express();
var httpServer = http.createServer(app);

/*
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    console.log("Received GET request for resource /");
    res.sendFile('index.html', { root: __dirname });
});
*/

//app.use(express.static('src'));

var myLogStatement = function(req, res, next) {
    console.log("Received", req.method, "request for resource", req.path, "from", req.ip);
    next(); // callback to the middleware function
}

app.use(myLogStatement);

httpServer.listen(3000, function(){
    console.log("Listening on port 3000");
});
```

Then I can't load my HTML page correctly. I got Cannot GET / in localhost:3000.

But if I use

```
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    console.log("Received GET request for resource /");
    res.sendFile('index.html', { root: __dirname });
});
```

or

```
app.use(express.static('src'));
```

Then my HTML could be loaded correctly.

Anyone could help me figure it out? Thanks!

Comment: Did you try to move the middleware function above `get` or `use(express.static)`?

Answer (score 1):

httpServer is used on vanilla node.js, that means you can run a server without express included. But since you included express, you have to use `app` now for handling routes. Here is the official docs of nodejs, try to read this and implement httpServer if you want to use it https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/getting-started-guide/

Comment: Agree with @Ryan. ExpressJS is a wrapper around vanilla NodeJS HTTP. ExpressJS makes life easy for all backend NodeJS developers.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to mention that your code is absolutely correct but incomplete. You get an error: `Cannot GET /`, because you have not implemented it. By default, Nodejs would not know which route to use and for which verb.

However both `app.get('/'...` and `app.get(express.static...` works simply because you are mentioning the route(in your case '/') and verb(in your case 'GET').

Please use the below snippet, it works.

> Note: I have removed the HTTP module as it's not required.

```js
var express = require('express');

var app = express();


var myLogStatement = function(req, res, next) {
    console.log("Received", req.method, "request for resource", req.path, "from", req.ip);
    next(); // callback to the middleware function
}

app.use(myLogStatement);

// add route
app.get('/', (_, res) => {
  res.status(200).send('Got you!');
});

app.listen(3000, function(){
    console.log("Listening on port 3000");
});
```